# Why does ':bufdo set fo=*' change window contents?

Tags: buffers, multiple-files

I have two files open, say `File.h` and `File.m` in separate tabs.

```
-----------------------------------
| File.h         |  File.m        |
-----------------------------------
```

`:ls` reveals

```
:ls
  1 %a   "File.h" line 1
  2  a   "File.m" line 0
```

When I run

```
:bufdo set fo=croql
```

I suddenly have two tabs with the same content

```
-----------------------------------
| File.m         |  File.m        |
-----------------------------------
```

but `:ls` gives the output

```
:ls
  1 #    "File1.h" line 1
  2 %a   "File2.m" line 1
```

I don't understand from the documentation what the `#` char means here, except that I can `:e #` to get back to the initial configuration.

Can somebody elucidate what is happening here?

Comment: `:bufdo` doesn't know about tabs, it opens every buffer in the current tab and runs your command on it. The `#` refers to the "alternate file name", which is the "last file name" AFAIK. It's to easily switch between 2 files (like `cd -`). This is a "buffer-based workflow" versus a "tab-based workflow" thing (they don't always mix very well).

Comment: I see. So in this case `tabdo` would be the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps also use `setlocal` instead of `set`?  It doesn't make much sense to set the same global option several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help :bufdo` explains very clearly how `:bufdo` works:

```
:bfirst
:{cmd}
:bnext
:{cmd}
etc.
```

The last buffer to be visited becomes the current buffer (`%`), and the buffer visited just before becomes the alternate buffer (`#`).

`:tabdo` doesn't care about buffers so it's most likely to be the right command for you.

Comment: If you hate that behaviour of `:bufdo` then you can use [my `:BufDo` command](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/77f1e3e79c89105716f2e9cd7d6414b3237d9e05/.vim/plugin/joeycommands.vim#L161-175) which returns you to the buffer you started on.